# Is there a way to remove the date from the SyncFusion Scheduler tooltip?

Tags: blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

I'm creating a week schedule that repeats over and over making any date irrelevant. To do this, I'm using SyncFusion's Scheduler with Blazor. I've removed the date from most other places, but it still remains on the hover tooltip and when you select a particular event.

Is there a way to remove just the date from these and leave everything else?

For further clarification, I want to exclusively remove the bits of information that are underlined in red in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This should be placed inside the `<ScheduleEventSettings>` tag.

```
<TooltipTemplate>
    <div class="tooltip-wrap">
        <div>@((context as AppointmentData).Subject)</div>
        <div>@((context as AppointmentData).Location)</div>
        <div>From&nbsp;:&nbsp;@((context as AppointmentData).StartTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"))</div>
        <div>To&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;@((context as AppointmentData).EndTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"))</div>
    </div>
</TooltipTemplate>
```

If you'd prefer it in 24-hour time, instead of putting `.ToString("hh:mm tt")` after `StartTime` and `EndTime`, put `.TimeOfDay`.

Keep in mind, this is only for the tooltip and not the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the requirement by using the TooltipTemplate in the Schedule component to customize the necessary functionality. For reference, please see the attached demo and user guide below.

Demo: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/scheduler/tooltip-template?theme=fluent

UG: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/scheduler/appointments#customizing-event-tooltip-using-template

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm already ahead of you on that. I submitted my own answer yesterday.

Comment: If you happen to know how I could also remove the date from the other box, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).